# Asp.net mvc Forms Authentication Prevent user from been automatically logged when created

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

Asp.net mvc 4 application, with Forms Authentication, I have a admin role who adds users to the application, but when I create a new user it automatically logs the new created user in, how can i prevent this?

here's my register action in the account controller

```
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(string username, string password)
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
        Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "Mechanic");
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
    }
```

Comment: Any code? Hard to know without seeing the implementation you are using.

Comment: Added register method, Will I add any more?

Comment: remove SetAuthCookie line  and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(string username, string password)
{
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
    Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "Mechanic");

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
}
```